Generate a .spec.ts file for Angular components
I have few components in my Angular project where the .spec.ts files were deleted. I tried creating a file through the IDE and renaming it to the same name as the component with .spec.ts as a suffix but the test cases written on that file are not run.
How can I generate a test file for these components? The project is made in Angular 15.
I tried creating a file manually through the IDE, I use WebStorm BTW. The test cases that were written in this file are never run when I use ng test --no-watch --code-coverage.
I tried using the command ng g component component.name --spec-only but that said --spec-only is unknown on the terminal.

There is no command to generate test files for existing components, services, etc. The documentation (https://angular.dev/cli/generate ) does not have a section for tests and only mentions how to skip tests when generating a new component.
So sadly, you have to do it yourself. Alternatively, you can regenerate the components fully and delete everything but the component or service. But both are not really satisfying.

This is possible to generate deleted spec.ts files in Angular.
You just need to run the following command :
ng generate component path of component/component-name --skip-import

Alter above command according to the path of your component, it will generate spec.ts file for your targeted component and also a component file. You can delete new component file and can use spec.ts file.

ng generate component <component-name> --skip-tests=false

